# Anime about a city where you must not lose your mask, otherwise you lose your face

Tags: story-identification, anime, dystopia

I remember the first chapter where the main character is visiting a city with his/her pet (I don’t remember the gender or if the pet was a human). The thing is you don’t have to lose your mask because you will lose your face (I’m not sure if it’s face, personality or you die). In the first chapter there are so many people without faces (like zombies) looking for any mask.

I’m pretty sure it’s not an 80’s or 90’s anime, and it’s not a movie because of the animation and I remember a list of chapters.

Comment: I doubt if you are thinking of the Fritz Leiber story Coming Attraction but masks figure prominently in it. It is a strange story indeed.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a manga or an anime? You say "chapter", which makes me think manga (and admittedly I first thought of High Rise Invasion for this), but you also say it's not a movie because of its animation. Is it an anime with "chapters" being the episode separator? Or by "chapters" do you mean "episodes"?

Comment: "you don’t have to lose your mask because you will lose your face" -- reminds me of Moon Moth by Jack Vance.

Comment: I’ve found it!, I’m really sorry it wasn’t an anime show, it’s a manga named City of Blank. Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: @yoanguila No problem! You should be able to post that as an answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 5):

OP found their answer in [a comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/232540/anime-about-a-city-where-you-must-not-lose-your-mask-or-you-lose-your-face#comment637356_232540), but did not come back to write it as an answer.

This is actually not an anime, but a Webtoon named [*City of Blank*](https://www.webtoons.com/en/sf/city-of-blank/list?title_no=1895&page=3), drawn and scenarised by 66.

> In a world where ghostly Blanks can steal your face – and your life – at any moment, a young boy named Rex hunts for his brother’s killer. Cursed with the unique power to physically touch Blanks, Rex starts to uncover darker secrets at the city’s center and in his own past. Will Rex unmask the killer, or will he become just another faceless victim in the City of Blank?

The art is pretty nice, and I can see why one could mistakenly remember it as an anime, see the following extracts from the first chapter:

[image: main masked character and his pet, a black/brown dog, being driven in a pick-up by another masked character warning them about losing your mask]

The titular "blanks" are the faceless people:

[image: ghostly purple figures]

Comment: I've just finished reading what's been published so far, and I highly recommend it.

Comment: Three and a half years later, I'm still reading this webtoon and finding it awesome, FWIW. :)